# Start hostednetwork using batch file

Tags: batch-file, host, hotspot

When I want to start a local hotspot, I normally run cmd as administrator and type the command
`netsh wlan start hostednetwork` . It wastes of time to run cmd and type this command. Is there any alternative way to do it using bat file?

Comment: A batch file is a text file containing cmd commands. Just take what you have and paste it into a batch file.

Comment: @SomethingDark But I need to run cmd and administrator!

Answer (score 5):

Might be late, but save only this line into .bat file:

> netsh wlan start hostednetwork

And then use any .bat to .exe converter like this one: [Advanced BAT to EXE Converter](http://www.battoexeconverter.com/downloads/advancedbattoexeconverter.exe)  OR you can use anyone else you like.

Convert it, right click on the new one, *Properties* -> *Compatibility* -> *Run this program as an administrator*

Double click the new .exe file, and there you go!

**You need to set the hostednetwork for the first time if you haven't before using this line:**

> netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=SSID_NAME key=PASSWORD

---

**IFF** you want to run your hostednetwork at startup:

- Open Run (Windows key + R)
- type: shell:startup
- Then copy the .exe file you made previously in that folder.

*You may need to enable "Run as an administrator" option for that program after moving it to **startup** folder.*

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Mithrandir0x/5620566), in resume just write this into a batch-File

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=SSID_NAME key=PASSWORD
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
pause
```

Comment: It is not work!!! This is just run cmd as a normal user. It requires administrator privilege. The message is as follow: `You must run this command from a command prompt with administrator privilege`

Comment: Ok so click right on the cmd and click on "open as administrator"

Comment: I know that method but it wastes of time. What I want is to create a batch file. So I just double click on it to host my hotspot :)

Comment: Right-click on the batch file and run it as administrator! :)

Comment: Just make the file to run always as administrator

Answer (score 0):

Me too, I don't want run command every create wifi, so I find a solution, that is create shortcut. It's easier than creating batch-file.

```
      Start:  netsh wlan start hostednetwork

      Stop:  netsh wlan stop hostednetwork

      Right click shortcut / Properties / Advanced / Tick Run as administrator/ ok / Apply / ok.
```

You cant watch on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhBn0TOkd8c&index=1&list=PLfuUuaDkOqwfCD4pwuDuzJARi_K-j71it), this is tutorial video.