# Execute batch-file to start wifi hotspot as admin

Tags: batch-file, cmd, notepad

I'm using windows 10 and I often have to start a wifi hotspot manually from `cmd`. So, I was thinking maybe I could write some code so that I don't have to write the commands again and again but I have no experience with .bat files.

This is how I start the hotspot:

1. Open `cmd` as administrator
2. `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=AdHoc key=password`
3. `netsh wlan start hostednetwork`

Comment: Put your `NETSH` command in a file and save the file with a .bat extension.

Comment: Ya there really isn't anything special.

Comment: You can run any .bat file as admin by right-clicking it and choosing run as administrator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hardest part of this is to run a .bat file as admin automatically, without even right-clicking on it. You need to save this code as a .bat file:

```
@ECHO OFF
:: this tests if the file is running as admin
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (GOTO askAdmin)
GOTO gotAdmin
:askAdmin
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
echo Requesting administrative privileges...
goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )
:UACPrompt
echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
"%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
exit /B
:gotAdmin
if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
::from this point you can execute your command as admin
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=AdHoc key=password
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

Note that this does show the "Run this program as admin?" prompt when started without administrative priviliges, but if you right-click this batch-file and choose run as admin it should immediately execute the command you want it to execute

Comment: I was going to flag this post as duplicate, but this answer is so good. Consider answering the original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28401704/start-hostednetwork-using-batch-file

Answer (score 0):

Oh, this is solution for you.

Let create shortcut, every you want turn on wifi, you need only click => ok !

> - **Start:**  netsh wlan start hostednetwork
> - **Stop:**  netsh wlan stop hostednetwork

Right click shortcut / Properties / Advanced... / Tick Run as
administrator/ ok / Apply / ok.

Example: [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhBn0TOkd8c&index=1&list=PLfuUuaDkOqwfCD4pwuDuzJARi_K-j71it).