# How to create a program that run batch file

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, cmd

I have find batch file that start wifi hotspot automaticaly ,So I need to make a program in visual studio to run that batch file

[Execute batch-file to start wifi hotspot as admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33787279/execute-batch-file-to-start-wifi-hotspot-as-admin)

Comment: What's your actual question? What have you tried? And what's wrong with the answer you link to? As it stands it's unclear what you're actually asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Start the child process.
Process p = new Process();
// Redirect the output stream of the child process.
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "YOURBATCHFILE.bat";
p.Start();
// Do not wait for the child process to exit before
// reading to the end of its redirected stream.
// p.WaitForExit();
// Read the output stream first and then wait.
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Code is from MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Write a program containing this line of code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("c:\\batchfilename.bat");
```

Should work for your belonings.